# Notificaciones en android

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, sketchware

Hola quiero que mi aplicación mande una notificación cuando toco un botón pero no sucede no se que hice mal estoy usando esto (trabajo con sketchware):

```
Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this);
mBuilder.setSmallicon(R.drawable.ic_android_black);
mBuilder.setContentTitle("titulo");
mBuilder.setContentText("mensaje");
mBuilder.setDefaults( Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContent(), 0, notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: Podrías decirnos cuál es el error o lo que no funciona?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No has llamado al evento notify :

```
notificationManager.notify(1,mBuilder.build());
```

Como parametro recibe el id de la notificacion que puede ser cualquier entero,y  Notification.Builder

Te paso un ejemplo de como crear una notificacion personalizada,para poner tu propio sonido ,icono,efectos etc.

```
  private void showNotification(String cabezera, String cuerpo,String id_grupo){
    ///Envio de valores por El Bundle
    Intent i = new Intent(this,ChatGrupo.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    i.putExtra("key_grupo",id_grupo);
    i.putExtra("label_name",cabezera);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    int icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
    Uri soundNotification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setContentTitle(cabezera);
    builder.setContentText(cuerpo);
    builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_LOW);
    builder.setSound(soundNotification);
    builder.setSmallIcon(icon);
    builder.setContentInfo("Chat");
    builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    builder.setTicker(cuerpo);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    ///Random devuelve un numero entero Aleatorio con su metodo nexInt()
    ////esto ayudara a que cada notificacion sea unica y no sea pisada por una nueva.
    Random random = new Random();

    notificationManager.notify(random.nextInt(),builder.build());



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gracias ya lo e solucionado lo correcto sera:

```
Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this);
mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_cloud_done_white);
mBuilder.setContentTitle("Tienes conexión");
mBuilder.setContentText("Ya tienes conexión a internet");
mBuilder.setDefaults( Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setAutoCancel(true);
notificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```